# mail () как правильно прикрутить уведомление о прочтении?

Tags: php, email

Нужно вставить в заголовок письма
`Disposition-Notification-To: '.$email.' или X-Confirm-Reading-To: '.$email.'`

Сам обработчик заканчивается так

```
$headers = 'From: '.$From.' <'.$email.'>';
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-utf-8';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Что то не получается у меня нарисуйте мне как надо или предложите альтернативную версию - как уведомить что письмо было прочитано?

Comment: Не стоит минусовать и тем более закрывать такие вопросы только за на плохую исходную реализацию. Сам по себе вопрос идеально подходит для этого сайта, а подробный ответ на него поможет множеству программистов.

Comment: Не вижу смысла редактировать "Вопрос", потому что и так понятна задача ... оно или работает или нет ))) а мы все ищем тот код который работает... если не можем сами написать (принцип цитирования) кто-то пишет кто-то использует написанное для цитат

Answer (score 2):

1. согласно [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php):

   > Несколько дополнительных заголовков должны быть разделены CRLF (\r\n)

   т.е., ориентируясь на применённый вами стиль, надо писать примерно так:

   ```
   headers = 'первый добавочный заголовок\r\n';
   headers .= 'второй добавочный заголовок\r\n';
   ```

   и так далее.
2. даже если вы все заголовки сформируете совершенно верно, не стоит ожидать получения «уведомления о прочтении». ведь для этого почтовый клиент вашего респондента должен: а) уметь это делать и б) быть настроенным так делать. мой личный опыт и здравый смысл подсказывают, что такое сочетание встречается довольно редко.

Comment: Это плохой ответ на вопрос. Он поучает автора конкретного вопроса, но не дает никакой помощи человеку, пришедшему из гугла по запросу php mail уведомление о прочтении

Comment: @Ипатьев, я буду только рад, если вы напишете более полезный ответ.

Comment: я знаю про CRLF (\r\n) и сам бы писал с подобным окончанием строк в заголовке, но код был скопирован из очень популярной платной CMS ... а у меня правило "если работает, значит не исправляем" ибо написать можно, что угодно (браузеры пошли умные читают правильно то что написано криво)